# How to replace TCL sublists

Tags: list, replace, tcl

There is a list of list in Tcl.

```
set somelist {{aaa 1} {bbb 2} {ccc 1}}
```

How to replace the first list's element so the new list will look like I had done:

```
set somelist {{xxx 1} {bbb 2} {ccc 1}}
```

I tried to do this with `lreplace`, but it doesn't work.

```
lreplace somelist 0 1 {xxx 1}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [`lreplace`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lreplace.htm) command takes a **list value** as the first argument, not a variable name, so you would do

```
set somelist {{aaa 1} {bbb 2} {ccc 1}}
set somelist [lreplace $somelist 0 0 {xxx 1}]
```

Or, use [`lset`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lset.htm), which is specifically for this case:

```
set somelist {{aaa 1} {bbb 2} {ccc 1}}
lset somelist 0 {xxx 1}
```

With `lset`, you can drill into sublists easily. For example, to change {bbb 2} to {bbb 42}, you could do

```
lset somelist {1 end} 42
```

Comment: +1 But I think that for the particular case, `lset somelist {0 0} xxx`  would the the one OP is looking for.